# Retrieve all details with least timestamp using java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data, java-11

Hello I working on a scenario, where I need the latest timestamp data based on Currency using Java 8.

Suppose I'm requesting for USD currency then I should get all USD data with Least timestamp for all date.

```
class Currency{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private LocalDateTime lastReceived;
}
```

Record In Database As below.

```
ID NAME  LAST_RECEIVED
-- ----  -------------
1  USD   18-MAY-22 09.04.01.545899000 AM
2  USD   18-MAY-22 08.04.01.545899000 AM
3  USD   19-MAY-22 08.04.01.545899000 AM
4  USD   20-MAY-22 08.04.01.545899000 AM
5  USD   20-MAY-22 11.04.01.545899000 AM
6  BUSD   18-MAY-22 08.04.01.545899000 AM

Expected:
ID NAME  LAST_RECEIVED
-- ----  -------------
1  USD   18-MAY-22 09.04.01.545899000 AM
3  USD   19-MAY-22 08.04.01.545899000 AM
5  USD   20-MAY-22 11.04.01.545899000 AM
```

I tried,
Suppose I requested for USD Data,

```
List<Currency> listCurrency = repo.getAllDataBasedOnCurrency("USD");

listCurrency.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());

// But here I want latest received Data for a single date.
```

Comment: `lastReceived` isn't a datetime type so that won't work. Make it a proper datetime type both in the database and the java code.

Comment: Is `repo` an Spring JPA Repository or self-made?

Comment: Spring JPA with queryDSL

Comment: If it really is a datetime write a proper query instead of retrieving everything and filter in memory.

Comment: I would go with `repo.findFirstByNameOrderByLastReceivedDesc("USD")`

Comment: Ok, Let me try, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you should group by currency **AND** date and then select by maximal (most recent) timestamp, this results in a map, and then you can use the map's `values()` to build the list.

So, a list of currency name and the date can be used as the key in the map, and `Collectors.collectingAndThen` is needed to convert the `Optional` result of `Collectors.maxBy` into the currency instance:

```java
List<Currency> lastByDate = new ArrayList<>(data
        .stream() // Stream<Currency>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            // key = List<Serializable & Comparable<? extends Comparable<?>>>
            curr -> Arrays.asList(curr.getName(), curr.getLastReceived().toLocalDate()),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived)),
                Optional::get // Optional<Currency> -> Currency
            )
        )) // Map<List<...>, Currency>
        .values()
);
```

If a sorted list is required, it may be retrieved by sorting the stream of `values`:

```java
List<Currency> sortedByDateAndCurr = data
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                curr -> Arrays.asList(curr.getName(), curr.getLastReceived().toLocalDate()),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived)),
                        Optional::get
                )
        ))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .sorted(
            Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived)
                      .thenComparing(Currency::getName)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or just by sorting the unsorted list:

```java
lastByDate.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived)
              .thenComparing(Currency::getName)
);
```

---

For a specific currency (e.g. `USD`) the implementation should be changed slightly to include filtering by the currency name then a simpler key should be created in the map:

```java
List<Currency> lastUSDByDate = new ArrayList<>(data
    .stream()
    .filter(curr -> "USD".equalsIgnoreCase(curr.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        curr -> curr.getLastReceived().toLocalDate(),
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived)),
                Optional::get
        )
    ))
    .values()
);
lastUSDByDate.sort(Comparator.comparing(Currency::getLastReceived));
```

---

Similar result may be achieved by building a native SQL query using a window function to get the most recent value per date.  JPA does not seem to support yet the window functions.

An example for PostgreSQL

```java
// some JPA CurrencyRepository
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
    SELECT id, name, last_received
    FROM (
        SELECT c.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY name, to_char(last_received, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
            ORDER BY last_received DESC
        ) AS rr
        FROM Currency c
        WHERE c.name = :currName
    ) tbl
    WHERE rr = 1
    ORDER BY last_received
""")
List<Currency> findLastByDateByCurrencyName(@Param("currName") currName);
```